# How can I make a localhost address be usable by other devices on the network?

Tags: c#, networking, localhost

I've created a simple web server by using the code from this website
https://codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/Simple-C-Web-Server

Now, I need to be able to access the web server from other devices on the network.

So, far I've tried using ngrok and pagekite but none of them worked.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: you have to allow it thru your local firewall.

Comment: i've tried adding the port to the inbound rules